# Why did Muslims become a target after 1857's Sepoy Mutiny?

Tags: muslims, indian-rebellion-1857

Hindus were involved in the 1857's Sepoy Mutiny and played some significant roles. E.g.,  Mongol Panday is said to initiate the mutiny. Then we know Tatya Tope, Nana Sahib Peshwa II, Queen of Jhansi - Laxmi Bai, Kunwar Sing of Jagdishpur, Gwalior State army, Kushal Sing Auwa of Jodhpur, etc.

However, after the mutiny, mainly Muslims became a target for British authorities. For the first time, Muslims were seen and identified as a real minority.  The *Martial Race* theory was abandoned, and the British Indian army was heavily reformed. Hindus were given preference in civil government jobs. Therefore, Muslims became the main losers.

- [Here is a quote](https://books.google.pl/books?id=bBOMDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=Sir%20William%20Wilson%20Hunter%20(d.%201900),%20a%20crucial%20example,%20both%20fostered%20and%20invested%20in%20the%20minoritization%20of%20Muslims.%20Making%20Muslims%20a%20minority%20%E2%80%93%20outsiders,%20disempowered,%20and%20both%20unique%20and%20uniquely%20problematic%20%E2%80%93%20is%20a%20key%20outcome,%20if%20not%20a%20stated%20goal,%20of%20The%20Indian%20Musalmans:%20Are%20They%20Bound%20in%20Conscience%20to%20Rebel%20Against%20the%20Queen?%20(1871;%202nd%20ed.%201872,%20reprinted%201876).&source=bl&ots=_7HYF3YtM7&sig=ACfU3U2ZdwL5ipa8I5qxAbvnLVaWSkxmtQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCr_nYwtL6AhVqw4sKHfk6Bi0Q6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=Sir%20William%20Wilson%20Hunter%20(d.%201900)%2C%20a%20crucial%20example%2C%20both%20fostered%20and%20invested%20in%20the%20minoritization%20of%20Muslims.%20Making%20Muslims%20a%20minority%20%E2%80%93%20outsiders%2C%20disempowered%2C%20and%20both%20unique%20and%20uniquely%20problematic%20%E2%80%93%20is%20a%20key%20outcome%2C%20if%20not%20a%20stated%20goal%2C%20of%20The%20Indian%20Musalmans%3A%20Are%20They%20Bound%20in%20Conscience%20to%20Rebel%20Against%20the%20Queen%3F%20(1871%3B%202nd%20ed.%201872%2C%20reprinted%201876).&f=false) from a book:

> Sir William Wilson Hunter (d. 1900), a crucial example, both fostered and invested in the minoritization of Muslims. Making Muslims a minority – outsiders, disempowered, and both unique and uniquely problematic – is a key outcome, if not a stated goal, of *The Indian Musalmans: Are They Bound in Conscience to Rebel Against the Queen?* (1871; 2nd ed. 1872, reprinted 1876).

Why was that?

Why did Muslims become a target after 1857's Sepoy Mutiny?

Answer (score 2):

"Sepoy" was a name given to a retributed soldier engaged by trade companies in India. As a whole, it included Muslim as well as Hindu soldiers. The mutiny was mainly caused by Hindu soldiers but Muslim soldiers participated as well.

In the 1860s and 1870s, other rebellion events triggered suspicion by the British about Muslim subjects that were geographically and culturally close to Afghanistan and Central Asia, where the British had difficulty to go and become sovereign. This explains the treatment of the Muslims in India as a problematic minority. This has not a lot to do with the Sepoy Mutiny.

But not that besides the current of "theorizing the race" that spread in the end of the 19th century (it was about measuring heads to measure intelligence, theories about the genetics of crime (see Zola), etc...) and address nearly every specific population as having specific features; besides that, the Muslims were left in the administration and military works and had their place there, like the [Punjabis](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44231691).

Comment: On the right track, but too short. The second (middle) paragraph is vague.

Comment: Note: I didn't DV the answer.

Comment: @user366312 I'll rewrite the vague part. Actually one aspect of the answer (the third paragraph) is about negating the initial part of the question: Where muslims unfavoured?